# How does an the ARM branch instruction address work?

Tags: assembly, arm

I know that an ARM instruction is 32 bits in size and therefore in memory it take up 4 memory locations (each location can store 8 bits)

But am confused on how a branch instruction address works

When using e.g. a Branch instruction

4 bits are used for the operation 
4 bits for the condition
24 bits for where to branch

Why is an address 4 * 24 bits? - I thought every instruction address was 32 bits

what does it mean by the 24 bit number being an offset?

Comment: See Michaels answer.  When you look at say x86 with 8 bit instructions your offset has to be byte based there are no alignment assumptions.  But with arm and mips and some others there are alignment assumptions, actually rules not assumptions so the offset (what you add to a base) is in units of instructions when encoded in the instruction, but converted to bytes (multiply by 2 or 4 depending on thumb vs arm) and add that offset to the base (pc plus an offset 2 or 4)

Comment: This opcode is known as “PIC” or “pc independent code”.  It allows code to run at any address and can be very handy for enabling an MMU and setting up sdram etc.  You have to look at each opcode to see how it uses addresses, for instance register with offset also has limitations which some huge structure could hit.

Answer (score 4):

From the ARM7TDMI manual:

> Branch instructions contain a signed 2's complement 24 bit offset. This is shifted left
>   two bits, sign extended to 32 bits, and added to the PC. The instruction can therefore
>   specify a branch of +/- 32Mbytes.

*Offset* in this case means that it's relative to the current `PC`.

The reason the offset is shifted by 2 bits (i.e. multiplied by 4) is that every instruction is required to be word aligned, i.e. instructions have to be located at an address that is a multiple of 4. The two least significant bits of all such addresses are always zero. Since you know that they are always zero you can store a 26-bit offset in 24 bits by omitting those two least significant bits.

Answer (score 2):

Such a branch instruction can only jump a distance of +/- 2^25 bytes from the current PC (26 bits for the jump, including the sign bit, minus two implied low-order zero bits, makes 24 bits).

If you want to jump further than that, you have to use e.g.

```
ldr r0,=DistantLabel
bx r0
```

Answer (score 1):

In the ARM architecture, the 32 bit instructions (or 16 bits for most Thumb state instructions) allow for 32 bits to encode both the instruction type and any operands used by that instruction.

Of these 32 bits, 4 are taken for conditional execution, leaving 28.
Of the remaining 28 bits, 4 of these are taken to break down the instructions into groups. This leaves 24 bits which are allocated to either additional sub-division of instruction behavior, register selection, or immediate values (program data which is encoded directly into the instruction opcode.)

Since 8 bits are already allocated to these first 2 functions, the largest immediate value which is possible in the 32 bit architecture is 24 bits. As described in the other answers, the relative branch instruction defines this 24 bit field as being used as a signed offset from the current location. In the 16/32 bit thumb instruction set, the offset which is available in a similar instruction is a little smaller, but it is still true that a large proportion of all of the branches in any program tend to be small (so it is rare to need to rely on a core register to calculate/hold the branch address).

In the 64 bit architecture, there is a similar discrepancy. Although the instructions are still only 32 bits, instruction addresses are now greater than 32 bits so there are potentially more large offset branches. In practice, these are still not really any more common within a single program (but might come into play when the operating system is switching context between one program and another - in which case the specific addresses will be already stored in data memory rather than as part of the instructions).

Comment: 32-8 is a 24-bit field, not 28.  (Also, typo: filled / field).  And BTW, even Thumb 1 uses a pair of 16-bit instructions for branches, allowing a reasonable displacement.  (Unlike Thumb 2, Thumb 1 doesn't have any 32-bit instructions, but there's a special case where the first instruction gives context for a following branch.  In practice I'd guess modern CPUs decode it as a single 32-bit instruction.)  See also https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/branch-and-call-sequences-explained.

Comment: See [How is the offset calculated in this Assembly Code (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53981739) for an example of Thumb `bl`.