# ARM AArch32 local labels vs named labels speed

Tags: assembly, arm

I know local labels are more like PC relative jumps and they need a search direction specified, and I know named labels don't need a direction specified and instead just jump.

Am I correct in believing that local labels are more like iterating through memory until the label is hit and named labels are more like discrete pre-known jumps? If so, does this make local labels significantly slower than named labels?

Comment: There is no performance difference at runtime.  When you jump to a label, you jump to the label.  At runtime, there is no process of finding the label like you imagine.

Comment: The "searching" is done by the assembler. In fact the cpu only sees addresses for both kinds of labels.

Comment: Depending on the length of the jump, one may require a pool value read from memory while local jump may not.  It varies a lot on the version of the assembler.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan local labels can require a pool value read. See [LDR pseudo-instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802a/Babbfdih.html)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a local label or a normal one. Whether you need a pool read does not depend on that. Once the assembler figured out which label is the target, the two kinds behave identically.

Comment: Or they can be encoded in the instruction - this is the point I am making:  Branch distance matters on 32-bit ARM, which is what OP is wondering about.  Relative branches can (cache cache cache...) be faster.

Comment: Distance matters, yes. OP did not ask about distance. Local labels are not limited by distance. It's just a different way to identify an address.

Comment: He asked if one was faster than the other.  This, the opposite of his guess, shows that relative could be faster. The system does not iterate until if finds a location though, a branch is a 1 stop branch, which was his other question.  Just wanted to be sure to fix his last statement...

Comment: You might be confused about what "local label" in this context means. It's a special [assembler feature](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Local-Labels-1). It's really just syntax for lazy programmers so they don't have to use proper names. Apart from that they work exactly the same as the named labels.

Comment: 2f, 3b, etc.  Yup - got that.  Never used that term :)  local jump though is probably not quite right though.  Either way, this horse is dead.  I ain't beatin' it anymore :)

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler, there are many (for this target).  So if this is an assembly question start there.  Next define what you mean by local labels, even labels in other functions can be done with a pc relative jump.  Also note there are a number of arm instruction sets which one are you asking about, it determines how far (much farther than an x86).  Also if you build position independent code you are asking for extra code that takes longer to execute, no matter how far the jump is.

Comment: ohh... is that what the question is 1: ...  b 1b vs  mylabel: ... b mylabel?  yeah there is no difference not relevant just a shortcut to typing in code.

Comment: @Jester: I strongly disagree that local labels are used by lazy programmers. Trying to meaningfully label some local block with a name can be harmful.  It is noise pollution.  Due to context it should be clear where a local label is (<4 locals).  Giving them some names is not usually helpful compared to one good comment on intent.  [Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer based off of @[Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester)'s comment

Since assembly is assembled by the assembler, it is the assembler's job to search for and de-tokenize the local labels' jumps while assembling the code. In fact the assembler has to do this with named labels too, it just pays attention to scope differently than with local labels.

All the CPU sees are the direct memory address jumps to make at runtime, so no, there is no difference in speed at runtime.

Comment: If the jump value is stored in a local pool, it may have to be read into a register from RAM before jumping - depending on the version of ARM we are talking about.  Newer has `movk` for this sort of work and is very quick.

Comment: The actual machine-code encoding of a branch has an *offset* that's added to PC, so it's a PC-relative encoding not absolute.  Anyway yes, this offset is a link-time constant.  This is efficient for nearby branch targets, but can't reach any arbitrary 32-bit address with one instruction.

Answer (score 0):

**Local labels have no difference in code efficiency**.

See: [ARM Branch instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944210/how-does-an-the-arm-branch-instruction-address-work) and [Heyrick's branch page](https://www.heyrick.co.uk/assembler/bl.html); the opcodes are they same no matter what.  A local label will not change the branch distance.

So why you might you use them?

There are three benefits of local labels.

1. They don't require a name which may clash with other labels (ie, `exit_routine:`).
2. They allow macros to contain 'local' labels.
3. Simpler can be better.

Comparing old_timers example,

```
1:
   ...
   b 1b
```

Versus,

```
my_label_which_is_to_long_and_obscures_intent_of_code_via_verbosity_57:
   ...
   b my_label_which_is_to_long_and_obscures_intent_of_code_via_verbosity_58
```

The label is ridiculous and all of the extra words just obscure the fact that it is probably jumping to the wrong place due to a copy/paste.  For this reason, many people use local labels because they don't really add much information to an assembler program in some places.  Ie, some calculation like,

```
start_calc:
   ; xxx
   cmp r0, #0
   bmi negative_case
;;; positive code
   ; xxx
   b done_calc
negative_case:
   ; xxx
done_calc:
```

Here `; xxx` represents a  a few simple instructions.  All of these labels are not too useful and a comment at the start as to why you need to handle negative/positive differently would be more helpful to most people.

Typical user interface guidelines give 4-7 options as this is easy for short term memory.  I wouldn't use more local labels than this in a row as it can become confusing.  However, I would argue that they can actually be helpful to understanding some code.

Comment: This does not answer the question, though it does make some good points. OP's question was about speed in resolving named vs local labels

Comment: @Stegosaurus: This answer does correctly say "they have no difference in code efficiency." in the last line.  It doesn't go into any detail why, but that's already covered in the other answer and comments.

Comment: @Stegosaurus  I did answer this, but it was fairly obscure due to it being at the end.  I thought that you and others had answered the question.  I tried to fix this to make it more clear; thank you.  The next question would be then why bother.  That was the main thing I was trying to answer.